# Generating random number of polygons and their XYZ values using for-loop

Tags: if-statement, maya, modeling, autodesk, mel

I've created a script that generates three types of different polygons with their `x` `y` `z` coordinates randomised. The current code generates those as desired, yet it always does 40 of each.

Next step would be to use an integer as a `random number generator` to generate a random number of each polygon type. This requires a `for` loop with one `if` statement, one `else-if` statement, and one `else` statement. The code will execute with the aforementioned arguments intact (since I've cancelled them), except it'll only do one type of polygon (with toruses untriggerable).

I'm skeptical about 2 things:

1: If the `int $rng=rand(1,4);` properly specifies to create a range of 1-4 to work with as the `random numbers`.

2: If a `for` loop with `if-else` statements is required to get a random number of all shapes in the first place.

[**This is a desired result I'm trying to get.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33qE6.png)
[This is the most recently-executed result of the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNNOL.png)

```
int $num = 40 ;
int $rng = rand( 1, 4 ) ;

for ( $i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++ ) {

    if ( $rng == 1 ) {

        polySphere -r 1 -sx 20 -sy 20 -ax 0 1 0 -cuv 2 -ch 1 ;
        int $xpos = rand( -20, 100 ) ;
        int $ypos = rand( 20, 80 ) ;
        int $zpos = rand( 20, 50 ) ;
        move -r $xpos $ypos $zpos ;
        print ( $i + "sphere \n" ) ;
    }   

    else if ( $rng == 4 ) {

        polyTorus -r 1 -sx 20 -sy 20 -ax 0 1 0 -cuv 2 -ch 1 ;
        int $xpos = rand( -20, 100 ) ;
        int $ypos = rand( 20, 80 ) ;
        int $zpos = rand( 20, 50 ) ;
        move -r $xpos $ypos $zpos ;        
        print ($i + "torus \n");    
    }   

    else {

        polyCube -w 1 -h 1 -d 1 -sx 1 -sy 1 -sz 1 -ax 0 1 0 -cuv 4 -ch 1 ;
        int $xpos = rand( -20, 100 ) ;
        int $ypos = rand( 20, 80 ) ;
        int $zpos = rand( 20, 50 ) ;
        move -r $xpos $ypos $zpos ;
        print ( $i + "cube \n" ) ;
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `$rng` inside the for loop otherwise it'll pick a random geometry and just create it 40 times instead of picking a random one every time.

In this case instead of using `if` `else` you can use `switch` to determine the different cases. You also don't need to repeat getting positions and moving them in all cases since they're doing the same thing. Removing them will make the script less bloated.

Here's an example in MEL:

```
int $num = 40;

for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
    int $rng = rand(0, 3); 

    float $xpos = rand(-20, 100);
    float $ypos = rand(20, 80);
    float $zpos = rand(20, 50);

    switch ($rng) {
        case 0:
            polySphere -r 1 -sx 20 -sy 20 -ax 0 1 0 -cuv 2 -ch 1;
            print ($i+1 + ": sphere \n");
            break;
        case 1:
            polyTorus -r 1 -sx 20 -sy 20 -ax 0 1 0 -cuv 2 -ch 1;
            print ($i+1 + ": torus \n");
            break;
        case 2:
            polyCube -w 1 -h 1 -d 1 -sx 1 -sy 1 -sz 1 -ax 0 1 0 -cuv 4 -ch 1;
            print ($i+1 + ": cube \n");
            break;
    }

    move -r $xpos $ypos $zpos;
}
```

and like-wise, here's the same code in Python, which I recommend you pick up instead as the language is more flexible, has a bigger community, and is much easier to learn:

```
import random
import maya.cmds as cmds

num = 40

for i in range(40):
    rng = random.randint(0, 3)

    xpos = random.uniform(-20, 100)
    ypos = random.uniform(20, 80)
    zpos = random.uniform(20, 50)

    if rng == 0:
        cmds.polySphere(r=1, sx=20, sy=20, ax=[0, 1, 0], cuv=2, ch=1)
        print "{0}: sphere \n".format(i+1)
    elif rng == 1:
        cmds.polyTorus(r=1, sx=20, sy=20, ax=[0, 1, 0], cuv=2, ch=1)
        print "{0}: torus \n".format(i+1)
    else:
        cmds.polyCube(w=1, h=1, d=1, sx=1, sy=1, sz=1, ax=[0, 1, 0], cuv=4, ch=1)
        print "{0}: cube \n".format(i+1)

    cmds.move(xpos, ypos, zpos, r=True)
```

Don't forget about your indentation and formatting; your code is a bit hard to read at the moment because of it :)